# How to save QGraphicsItem sizes on screen while scaling view?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I've got map (QGraphicsPixmapItem) and cursor (inheritor of QGraphicsItem, just cross).

For cursor I have set `QPen::setCosmetic(true)`

When one zoom in/out scene by `QGraphicsView::scale()`, cursor keep right position and line width,but also change own size.

If activate `QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations` then line width and size are correct, but pos is wrong.

How to manage with it?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
Pass view transform to your item.
Reimplemented method `setPos` should be like:

```
void YourItem::setPos(const QPointF & pos)
{
    auto centerItem = m_boundRect.center(); //boundRect of your item
    centerItem.rx() /= m_viewTransf.m11();
    centerItem.ry() /= m_viewTransf.m22();
    QGraphicsItem::setPos(pos - centerItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the *QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations* flag and try to scale position. That should fix the problem.

```
const auto& pos = cursor->pos();
const QPointF newPos(pos.x() * scaleX, pos.y() * scaleY);
view->scale(scaleX, scaleY);
cursor->setPos(newPos);
```

Comment: Nope.Problem happens when move cursor on already scaled view.View should apply his transform for correct setting of pos.